# Need to retrieve all excel column names in a list with Java Code

Tags: java, xml, tibco

I need to get all the column names from the excel file and it could be either .xls or .xlsx with the help of java code.
i will provide the file name and file directory as inputs and code need to read the file in the directory and capture all the columns in a list and send the output in xml format.

the below is the sample xml data and will have more columns than below

```
Location ID Location Name   Product ID  Supplier Name   
Invoice Number  Sales Qty   Buy Qty Inventory Qty

2-LG2-344   ABC BBC CBC AK1234  5   4   3

2-LG2-344   ABC CBC CBC AK1235  2   6   5

2-LG2-344   ABC DBC CBC AK1236  3   2   3



the output should be like 
<ptnr_label_names>
<field_name>Location ID<field_name>
<field_name>Location Name<field_name>
<field_name>Product ID<field_name>
<field_name>Supplier Name<field_name>
<field_name>Invoice Number<field_name>
<field_name>Sales Qty<field_name>
<field_name>Buy Qty<field_name>
<field_name>Inventory Qty<field_name>
</ptnr_label_names>
```

Comment: from excel file i need to get all the column names in a list as i mentioned above. the output can be a text but should be an XML as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html). A simple code would look like this:

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.xls");
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis); //or new XSSFWorkbook("test.xls")
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0); //assume first row is column header row
        System.out.println("<ptnr_label_names>");
        for(int col=0; col< numXolumns; col++){
           Cell cell = row.getCell(col);
           String columnName = cell.getStringCellValue();
           System.out.println("<field_name> "+columnName +"</field_name>");
       }
        System.out.println("</ptnr_label_names>");
```

Comment: can i use this code as it is without having any libraries and will it work for .xlsx also?

Comment: If you are referring MS-Excel, you need to use some API to read the file. `POI` is a nice open source from `Apache` to manage `XLS` files in Java.

Comment: how did you get the total no.of column count

Comment: That is a variable representing, how many columns you want to read.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the row where your column names are there in the excel file
and then read the cells by moving from one column to the other.

```
    Row row=sheet.getRow(r);//r is the row number for your column names
    Cell cell=row.getCell(c);//c is the column number
```

you need to iterate through each column by changing the value of `c` in above code.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a java bean to represent you data structure.
- Use Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/ to read excel to the bean.
- Use XStream http://x-stream.github.io/ to throw the bean to XML.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly:
"all the column names from the excel file and it could be either .xls"

I've attached as requested an excel fiel with Column ID in a list.
However, unable to create custom list with those, due to limit in excel.

[Excel ColumnID](http://rapidshare.com/share/54D77B922474BB825F01963B5A1B73FB)

Comment: Please also include key parts of the solution here, wihtout needing to visit the link.